# msonline module - where statements not working in azure functions powershell

Tags: azure-active-directory, powershell-core

I am trying to get a script working but any time I pipe a "where" or "Where-object" into it, I get zero results.

i.e.

```
$UserNames = Get-MsolUser -TenantId $tenantid -ALL | Where {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -ilike "*$($licenseName)"} | Sort-Object DisplayName
```

If I run the same script locally it works perfectly fine, but just does not work in functions.
If I remove the Where statement it runs fine.

Does this need a separate syntax in azure functions, or is it a deserialization issue for MSOnline module in azure function? Not sure how to fix.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using this workaround.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/232